# Flutter and Onesignal, hide notification

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I'm having a chat in my app with notifications about new messages being shown and I'm using OneSignal for this.

However if the chat is with the person and the notification is about the chat open at that moment, I'd like it to hide the notification (not completely mute though as I'm using it for the chat messages being added into the conversation as well).

Is this doable or do I have to do for example save the open chat into the database, then check whatkind of notification is to be sent based to the open chat? (which would of course cause many kinds of issues if the user just simply closes the app)

Should I somehow edit the state of:

```
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
}
```

Or is there another trick into this to achieve it?

Comment: Did you have an answer to this?

Comment: I did not. I just decided to send notification in every message no matter what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but if you do this: -

```
OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.none);
```

after you've initialized OneSignal it should do what you want

Comment: Hey thank you! I'm going to give this a go when I can.